# ExtJs Grid Remote Sorting and Remote filtering

Tags: sorting, extjs, filtering, extjs4.2, sencha-cmd

I have a grid in ExtJs 4.2. I need to apply  remote sorting, remort filtering and pagination. So my store look like this:

```
    storeId: 'mainStore',

    pageSize: 10,
    autoLoad: {
        start: 0,
        limit: 10
    },
    autoSync: true,

    remoteSort: 'true', //For Remote Sorting

    sorters: [{
        property: 'COM_KOP_Vertriebsprojektnummer'
        direction: 'ASC'
    }],

    remoteFilter: true, //For Remote Filtering 

    proxy: {
        type: 'rest',
        filterParam: 'filter',
        url: PfalzkomApp.Utilities.urlGetData(),
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': "application/xml"
        },
        reader: {
            type: 'xml',
            record: 'record',
            rootProperty: 'xmlData'
        }

   }
```

I do not want to set buffered = true case that will load my pages in advance and I have 1000 pages and I don't want to do that.

Remote filtering, Pagination, sorting is working fine **But when I try to filter** some thing, **a seprate request for sorting is going** as well. How can I stop it?

two requests when I try to filter some thing:

http://127.0.0.1/projektierungen/?_dc=1437058620730&page=1&start=0&limit=10&sort=[{"property":"COM_KOP_Vertriebsprojektnummer","direction":"DESC"}]

http://127.0.0.1/projektierungen/?_dc=1437058620734&page=1&start=0&limit=10&sort=[{"property":"COM_KOP_Vertriebsprojektnummer","direction":"DESC"}]&filter=[{"property":"COM_KOP_Vertriebsprojektnummer","value":"2882"}]

How can I stop the first request?

My code for filtering column is this:

```
{
                text: 'Vertriebsprojektnr',
                dataIndex: 'COM_KOP_Vertriebsprojektnummer',
                flex: 1,            
                items    : {
                    xtype:'textfield',
                    flex : 1,
                    margin: 2,
                    enableKeyEvents: true,
                    listeners: {
                        keyup: function() {
                            var store = Ext.getStore('mainStore');
                            store.clearFilter();
                            if (this.value) {
                                //debugger;
                                //debugger;
                                store.filter({
                                    property     : 'COM_KOP_Vertriebsprojektnummer',
                                    value         : this.value,
                                    anyMatch      : true,
                                    caseSensitive : false
                                });

                            }

                        },
                        buffer: 1000,

                    }
                }
            }
```

Due to this auto genrated request, my view is not working fine. As the result after filtering are replaced by this sorting request.
 Kindly help.

Comment: Why use custom `textfield` with `keyup` stuff instead of standard [column filter](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.3/#!/api/Ext.ux.grid.FiltersFeature)? Like [here for example](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.3/#!/example/grid-filtering/grid-filter-local.html)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The extra request is not there because of sorting but because of the call to `store.clearFilter()`. Try to call `store.clearFilter(true)` that suppresses the event what could prevent that extra request.

Comment: Thanks for your time. Your solution did work. But now I face a problem. If i write something in filter, let's say "2882-3", everything works.
Now if I remove it "COMPLETELY" by backspace, it doesn't fire a request. and hence last filtered result remain there until i press enter. Do you know what should I do ?

Comment: Because you're checking on value is empty, which it is at that time, you are not filtering or altering your current filter. The answer of Saki is not providing you with a solution, but only telling you why it called twice. Did you try my solution?

Answer (score 0):

Why are you clearing you filters when the value is empty? Why not filter on an empty value? I almost got the same situation, but I think my solution works well without clearing anything. Besides that I don't want to know which store to filter or have the property name hardcoded. Here is my filterfield:

```
Ext.define('Fiddle.form.TextField', {
    extend: 'Ext.form.field.Text',
    alias: 'widget.filterfield',

    emptyText: 'Filter',
    width: '100%',
    cls: 'filter',
    enableKeyEvents: true,
    listeners: {
        keyup: {
            fn: function(field, event, eOpts) {
                this.up('grid').getStore().filter(new Ext.util.Filter({
                    anyMatch: true,
                    disableOnEmpty: true,
                    property: field.up('gridcolumn').dataIndex,
                    value   : field.getValue()
                }));
            },
            buffer: 250
        }
    }
});
```

And here is the view declaration:

```
dataIndex: 'company',
text: 'Company',
flex: 1,
items: [{
    xtype: 'filterfield'
}]
```